Compose Type Safe Navigation . Convert to Route
I am building an app where I have a top scaffold so I am changing its heade based on the route because I cannot seem to get the current Desitnation KClass.
val scaffoldListElements = remember { myAppScaffoldListElements }
val navController = LocalNavHostContoller.current
val navBackStackEntry by navController.currentBackStackEntryAsState()
val currentRoute = navBackStackEntry?.destination?.route


MyAppTheme {
    val (topAppBar, bottomAppBar) = remember(currentRoute) {
        val currentScaffoldDestination = scaffoldListElements[currentRoute]
        Pair(
            first = currentScaffoldDestination?.topAppBar,
            second = currentScaffoldDestination?.bottomAppBar
        )
    }

    Scaffold(
        topBar = {
            AnimatedVisibility(topAppBar != null) {
                topAppBar?.invoke(navController)
            }
        }, ...

Routes for example:
@Serializable
data object FirstLogin {

    @Serializable
    data object FirstLoginScreen1

    @Serializable
    data class FirstLoginScreen2(val list: List<PropertyTagNavigation>)

The bar hasMap:
val myAppScaffoldListElements = buildMap {
    putAll(FIRST_LOGIN_SCAFFOLD_LIST_ELEMENTS)
}.toPersistentHashMap()

the Elements:
val FIRST_LOGIN_SCAFFOLD_LIST_ELEMENTS = hashMapOf(
    OwnerGraph.FirstLogin.FirstLoginScreen1::class.qualifiedName to MyAppScaffoldElement(
        topAppBar = { _ ->
            MyAppHeader(showBackButton = false)
        }
    ),
    OwnerGraph.FirstLogin.FirstLoginScreen2::class.qualifiedName to MyAppScaffoldElement(
        topAppBar = { navHostController ->
            MyAppHeader {
                navHostController.popBackStack()
            }
        }
    ),

And the problem happens with the FirstLoginScreen2 since it expects a value in its route:
The route is: com.corenter.ui.OwnerGraph.FirstLogin.FirstLoginScreen2/{list}
My list's supposed to be matching element: com.corenter.ui.OwnerGraph.FirstLogin.FirstLoginScreen2
Is there an alternative way I could approach this?
Is there some method where I could generate the matching route string for my Nav Type destinations?

You can check current NavBackStackEntry is generated from Klass with hasRoute(FirstLoginScreen2::class) and if it is then convert it to route with toRoute<FirstLoginScreen2>()
if (navBackStackEntry?.destination?.hasRoute(FirstLoginScreen2::class) == true) {
    val route = currentNavBackStackEntry?.toRoute<FirstLoginScreen2>()
    // Do something with list
    route.list
}

